# Sending confirmation letter template to client's email address

Tags: php

I am trying to send booking confirmation email to client. I've made a confirmation template using HTML and CSS where some data are generated from a php form. I am facing two problem now.(1) When i generate the template, instead and showing the template it shows only the SUBMIT button.(2) and without clicking the button the confirmation template automatically goes to the client email with the raw code of HTML and CSS. It does not shows the template in client's email. Can anyone help me to fix this? Note that i kept all my HTML and CSS code in a php variable ( $message ).

```
<?php   $message= '<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
table {
     width:100%;
    }
    table, th, td {
        border: 2px solid #ffffff;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
</style>
<body>

<div class="table">             
 <table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $_POST["guestname"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_POST["checkin"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_POST["checkout"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_POST["roomtype"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_POST["rate"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_POST["payment"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_POST["resno"]; ?></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div> <!-- table -->
'; ?>

<?php
    $to = "client@email.com";
    $subject = "My subject";
    $txt = "$message";
    $headers = "From: my@email.com" . "\r\n" .
    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
 <input type="submit" value="Send" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sending code you need to specify the content type of the mail and send it as a header, additionally you need to modify your PHP code like so

```
<?php
$message = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
        <style type="text/css">
            table {
                width:100%;
            }
            table, th, td {
                border: 2px solid #ffffff;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="table">
            <table id="t01">
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$_POST["guestname"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$_POST["checkin"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$_POST["checkout"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$_POST["roomtype"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$_POST["rate"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$_POST["payment"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$_POST["resno"].'</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div> <!-- table -->
    </body>
</html>';

//Set the headers and other mail data and mail it
$to = 'client@email.com';
$subject = 'My subject';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

// Additional headers
$headers[] = 'From: my@email.com';

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
?>
```

For further reference read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Thanks...this code is working nicely but i am facing another problem, that is whenever this confirmation page is generated the mail is sending automatically. I want to use a SEND BUTTON to send this to email. How can i do this?

Comment: @AmiHasan using html forms would be nice'

Answer (score 0):

Change your `tr` tag like this

```
 <tr>
    <td>'.$_POST["guestname"].'</td>
    <td>'.$_POST["checkin"].'</td>
    <td>'.$_POST["checkout"].'</td>
    <td>'.$_POST["roomtype"].'</td>
    <td>'.$_POST["rate"].'</td>
    <td>'.$_POST["payment"].'</td>
    <td>'.$_POST["resno"].'</td>
 </tr>
```

Your are using `php` tag inside `php` tag which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<?php` code inside `<?php`. Also set content type in mail header

try this:

```
<?php   $message= '<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
table {
     width:100%;
    }
    table, th, td {
        border: 2px solid #ffffff;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
</style>
<body>

<div class="table">             
 <table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <td>'.$_POST["guestname"].'</td>
    <td>'.$_POST["checkin"].'</td>
    <td>'.$_POST["checkout"].'</td>
    <td>'.$_POST["roomtype"].'</td>
    <td>'.$_POST["rate"].'</td>
    <td>'.$_POST["payment"].'</td>
    <td>'.$_POST["resno"].'</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div> <!-- table -->
'; ?>

<?php
    $to = "client@email.com";
    $subject = "My subject";
    $txt = "$message";
    $headers = "From: my@email.com" . "\r\n" ;
    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

?>
```